# Prevent Google Talk from being signed in all the time

Tags: google-talk

On my Sony Ericsson Xperia mini pro, stock ICS, Google Talk remains signed in all the time. Is there a setting - within Google Talk, in Sync settings, or otherwise - which can prevent Google Talk from signing in? I just don't like being online on IM clients and I don't want to be signed in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On all my android devices (3 HTC phones and an Asus Transformer), if you sign off gtalk manually (gtalk/menu/exit), gtalk does not reconnect again until you do it manually.

Comment: I can confirm this.  On Gingerbread, ICS and Jelly Bean (and quite possibly on earlier OS versions) if you sign out of Google Talk manually, it stays signed off.